# Android : How to set value from SQLlite Database to specific position of editText in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I am having `RecyclerView` in `Fragment`, Fetching data from `SQLite` Database and displaying in `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

Here, the problem is how to `setText` in `RecyclerViewAdapter` to specific position of item, based on `SQLite` Data?

**Fragment.class**

```
RecyclerView_Adapter adapter = new RecyclerView_Adapter(getActivity(), databaseHelper.getAllValues());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

From `Fragment`, am passing database values to `RecyclerViewAdapter` contains First and Fourth row of `editText` values form `SQLiteDatabaseHelper` query.

**RecyclerViewAdapter.class**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ViewHolder mainHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
    mainHolder.editText1.setText(schemeList.get(position).getValue());
}
```

Here `setText` of values setting in all rows of `RecyclerViewAdapter` items.

But I want to set values only in First and Fourth row of `editText`.

Please let me know if any ideas.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you mean 1st and 4th EditText of the RecyclerView?

Comment: Yes, I want to setText only in 1st and 4th EditText of the RecyclerView comparing with SQLite Database values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
if ((position == 0) || (position == 3)) {
    mainHolder.editText1.setText(schemeList.get(position).getValue());
}
```

Comment: I tried with your answer comparing like, `if (pos == Integer.parseInt(schemeList.get(position).getId()))` But setText value sets upto first 3 `editText` in `recyclerviewAdapter`.  Why because SQLite data having only 3 rows of data, after scrolling down to see 4th `editText` showing as `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @vijikrish What do you mean like? Try the code exactly as I posted it. The code you tried is wrong. if there are less than 4 items.